# How much data can be send in 1 minute of audio with Smartphone speakers / microphones?

Tags: data-compression, signal-processing

Having the current news about [Google Assistant](https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/08/the-google-assistant-will-soon-be-able-to-call-restaurants-and-make-a-reservations-for-you/) in mind, I thought that robots might use interfaces designed for humans to send data. Like a telephone interface.

Then I wondered: What is the maximum amount of data you can send in 1 minute when you have to use a "normal" voice setup?

### Setting 1

- One machine encodes the data in an audio signal and uses normal customer-grade speakers (for less than 50 EUR) to transmit it.
- Standard microphone (smartphone or other for less than 50 EUR) is used to receive the information.
- A normal silent room - only the fan of a computer can be heard.

**How much data could two devices in a room with only normal speakers and microphones transmit in one minute?**

### Setting 2

A lot simpler: If the smartphone can bypass the speaker / microphone restriction from setting 1, **how much data can be transfered in one minute via a normal telephone connection?**

### A lower bound

- I am convinced that the 10 (?) phone dial sounds can be distinguished easily
- I don't think you need more than 0.5s for that sound to distinguish two consecutive sounds

$\Rightarrow 10\text{Bit} / 0.5\text{s} = 20\frac{\text{Bit}}{\text{s}} = 120\frac{\text{Bit}}{\text{min}}$

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic here. Any community votes?  Setting 1: It all depends on how much ambient noise there is and the distortion introduced by the microphone and speaker.  I'm not sure that's really a matter of computer science; it sounds more like a property of the room and the specific devices you use.  Setting 2: Telephone calls are typically compressed.  It all depends on the compression settings chosen by your phone carrier.  It doesn't sound like a matter of computer science.

Comment: I do not think that your question is clear enough. I do not know what is bandwidth of less than 50€ microphone, what is your goal, what do you count as succesful transmission? Could it be lossy? If you are interested in pure capabilities the setting (helpful to understand the goal) is not relevant as specs of hardware (which looks like pure math then). The transmission in one minute, ok, how much time can we spend compressing? As D.W. pointed, the phone calls are compressed, so there will be some loss of data, which is ok with voice, but not with arbitrary data.

Comment: This seems better suited to [electronics.se]. It’s essentially a question about applied information theory.